# How to get a response with Selenium when a click() is sent to server? True or False status output

Tags: python, selenium

How should I check if the following is working?  What can I do, to get a true or false response?

```
 driver.find_element_by_link_text("XXXX").click()
```

Comment: If this is for testing purposes and you don't need it returned in python you can inspect element with chrome, and add an event listener like this: `document.getElementById("login-signin").addEventListener("click",function(){ alert("clicked")});`

Answer (score 1):

let's say when you fire a `.click` event, a **event occurs in UI** (for an example after clicking on **login button**, we see **dashboard page title or heading**)
what we would do in this case is to `assert` that `heading`, or `title`, if `assertion` works then `script` will get to know that **the previous .click** was actually done, cause if it was not then **assertion would have failed.**

```
try:
    driver.find_element_by_link_text('some text').click()
    # put some delay here, WebDriverWait or time.sleep()
    assert driver.find_element_by_xpath('dashboard page heading web xpath here').text in "expected dashboard heading"
    print('Assertion worked so .click was correct')
except:
    print('Assertion must have failed')
```

Answer (score 1):

Clicking on a link typically takes you to another window/tab. You can capture the title/url of that page and assert that click operation worked

```
try:
    ele=driver.find_element_by_link_text("XXXX")
    if (ele):
        print "this link exists in the page"
except:
    print("there is no such link in the page")
```